# about contact form

Tags: php, forms

Ok I am trying to get this form to where if someone skip something on the form it will come up and tell them. I am a newbie and I am not understanding on how to get that error to come up if someone dont enter the information. This is what I have

```
  <?php
 function showForm($strMessage){
echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
echo " <p>Note: fields marked with '*' are required</p>\n";
echo "<form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">\n";
echo "<table width=\"45%\" class=\"formtable\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvname\">* Name:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"   value=\"".$_POST['name']."\"  /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "    <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvemail\">* E-mail:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"".$_POST['emial']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "      <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvusername\">* Username:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" value=\"".$_POST['username']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "        <td><span id=\"rfvpword\">* Password:</span></td>\n";
echo "        <td><input type=\"password\" name=\"pword\" value=\"".$_POST['pword']."\" /><br /><span style=\"font-size:9px;\"><em>(at least 4 chars) </em></span></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "    <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvpword\">* Re-enter Password:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"repword\" value=\"".$_POST['repword']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "         <td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
echo "         <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btnSubmit\" id=\"btnSubmit\" name=\"submit\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Contact Form</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body{
        background-color:#FFBD40;
        color:#000000;
        font-size:100%;
        font-family:Georgia,Verdana,"Times New Roman",sans-serif;
     }


    #container{
        background:#FFF573;
        width:800px;
        margin:auto;
        padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
        border:6px double #000000;
      }
       </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container">
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (trim($_POST['name'])==""){
    $strMessage="Please enter your name!";
    showForm($strMessage);
   }
   elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['pword']))<=3){
    $strMessage="Your password must be at least 4 characters long!";
    showForm($strMessage);
  }
    else{
     $strMessage="Thank you, your information has been submitted. Below is the information you sent:";
     $strMessageBody.="Name: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']))."<br />";
     $strMessageBody.="E-mail: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']))."<br />";
     $strMessageBody.="UserName: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['username']))."<br />";
     $strMessageBody.="Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword']))."<br />";
     $strMessageBody.="Re-enter Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['repword']))."<br />";
    echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
    echo $strMessageBody;
}
   }
 else{
$strMessage= "Please fill out the form below to send your information:";
showForm($strMessage);
}
   ?>php
    $$errors = array();
    if (isset($_REQUEST["seen_already"])){
    validate_data();
    if(count($errors) ! = 0){
    display_errors();
    display_welcome();
    } else {
    display_welsome();
    }
    function validate_data()
    {
    global $errors;
    if($_REQUEST["Name"]==""){
    $errors[] = "<FONT COLOR='RED'>Please enter your first name</FONT>";
    }
    if($_REQUEST["E-mail"]==""){
    $error[] = "<FONT COLOR='RED'>Please enter your E-Mail>/FONT>";
    }
    if($_REQUEST["UserName"]==""){
            $errors[] = "<FONT COLOR='RED'>Please enter your Username</FONT>";
    }
    if($_REQUEST["Password"]==""){
            $errors[] = "<FONT COLOR='RED'>Please enter your Password</FONT>";
    }
    if($_REQUEST["RE-enter Password"]==""){
            $errors[] = "<FONT COLOR='RED'>Please  re-enter your Password</FONT>";
    }
   }
   function display_errors()
   {
      global $errors;

      foreach($errors as $err){
        echo $err, "<BR>";
        }
      }
      function process_data()


 </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Well the echo's and the "  and \ is how I have to set this all up. So it is suppose to look like that. And all i am asking is if someone can help me understand how to do the error code. Not to do it for me but help me understand it. Is the code i already started on will it work or am I doing it all messed up. And thank to whoever is voting me down.I am just asking a simple question.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: I dont know how to really do the error code and I am sure i probally aint doing it right. And for some reason I think this error code i am doing is really long

Comment: Andy, good IDE (NetBeans) will do big helpful work for your coding.

Comment: You **REALLY** need to read about HEREDOCs: http://php.net/heredoc A zillion echo statements with escapes galore is NOT the way to write readable PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
 $_REQUEST["RE-enter Password"]
```

You used the textual label for the form fields. But your actual input field is called:

```
 $_REQUEST["repword"]
```

Likewise for all the other fields. The `$_REQUEST` array holds the keys according to the `name=` attributes in the HTML form.

---

Something else: You can also simplify the form output. Instead of the many `echo`s you should use a [heredoc string](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid the many `"` dquotes and `\` backslash escapes:

```
echo <<<HTML
 <h1>$strMessage</h1>
 <p>Note: fields marked with '*' are required</p>
 <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">
 <table ...
      <td><span id="rfvname">* Name:</span></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="name"   value="$_POST[name]"></td>
 ...
HTML;
```

Also add `$_POST = array_map("htmlentities", $_POST);` before that (for simplicity/security).

Comment: yes there is sam cause i am confused on how to do the error code so i did stop that. and the " double quotes and \ because that is how i am suppose to...

Comment: The missing `}` at the end are probably due to the code being shortened? And I've ignored the HTML errors too (faux xhtml and font tags). The `validate_data()`, while not very readable without proper indendation, seems ok.

Comment: And in the function, `$_POST['emial']` is a typo. It should be `$_POST['email']`.